# HTTP 400 error not getting logged in spring boot although 404 and others do

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG,stdout
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=DEBUG,stdout
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.beans.cache.time-to-live=10s
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled = true
log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod=DEBUG,stdout
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG,stdout
```

Here,

```
CommonsRequestLoggingFilter
```

logs other requests but not 400. why is that? how can I handle this universally? I am fairly New to spring boot and have not been able to implement `restcontrolleradvice` yet

Controller:

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
public class DataController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/abc/track/{type}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public void DummFunc(                            
          @RequestParam(value="subs", required = false) String sub,
,  HttpServletResponse response) {}
// @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)


@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    public void handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION HAPPENED");
        System.out.println(e);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add the below code in your controller -

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public void handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
    logger.warn("Returning HTTP 400 Bad Request", e);
}
```

It would be globlally accessible if you add `@ControllerAdvice` at the `class` level.
Don't forgot to keep the class inside a package which can be scanned by Spring boot

Comment: I added this: package com.abc.deg.controller;


[@]ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandle {

    [@]ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public void handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION HAPPENED");
        System.out.println(e);
    }


}

Comment: but it did not get called. anything wrong with what I did?

Comment: That's good. Also please annotate the same class with `@Controller`

Comment: Also make sure your `Application class` has an annotation to scan the components and your package is scanned as `@ComponentScan(value = { "com.abc.deg.controller",... .. etc})`

Comment: Please note - the controller class you added does not have `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)` this part

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement `ControllerAdvice` and handle the exception, here the sample code:

```
 @ControllerAdvice
    @RestController
    public class CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

      @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
      public final ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
             ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
        request.getDescription(false));
            // doSomthing 
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
      }
```

Here my ExceptionResponse class:

```
public class ExceptionResponse {
  private Date timestamp;
  private String message;
  private String details;

  public ExceptionResponse(Date timestamp, String message, String details) {
    super();
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.message = message;
    this.details = details;
  }

  public Date getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  public String getDetails() {
    return details;
  }

}
```

Comment: Put break point then you will check this method is being called

Comment: I did. had put in sop inside as well. The control is not going in there

Comment: Add your controller class in question

Comment: Added stub but problem is request does not even enter controller and get rejected already

Comment: @Simrankaur : Are you using Global CORS Configuration please add WebMvcConfigurer code in your question